# Use Silverlight in Asp.Net WebSite

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, web

I've build new website with ASP.NET, but when I came to the design, I wanted some attractive look, so I thought if I can use silverlight to get this attractive look.

Actually I'm so new to silverlight, I don't really know how I can use Silverlight in my website (if I can). Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: i hope you get idea about using silverlight in asp.net website, dont forget upvote and mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want....

Comment: I'm tempted to down vote this.  It doesn't show any research effort.  This is not the place to learn Silverlight from scratch.  I would recommend not even using Silverlight.  We have it in one of our web apps and it is a pain.  The project lead wants to get rid of it, and I concur.  I suspect it is not going to find widespread usage anyway.  But if you must, buy a Silverlight book, like this one, $1.99 used, good book for beginners: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Silverlight-Step/dp/073563887X/ref=sr_1_7?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1340460321&sr=1-7&keywords=silverlight

Comment: I agree with gray fox, don't use silverlight just for visuals.  The only exception being that you wanted complex timeline/designer based animation.  Most things you can animate just fine with javascript.  Rounded corners, glows/shadows, etc are all pretty solved problems, lots of info out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can make use of silverlight component in asp.net website...** .

## MSDN LInks

[**Integrating Silverlight with a Web Page**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838145%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

[**Encapsulate Silverlight with ASP.NET Controls**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135987.aspx)

A Silverlight is embedded in an ASP.NET (or HTML) page using the object tag. That means that you can integrate it in existing pages quite easily and without changing any of the existing structure - you just have to find a place where you want to put the application into, or create a separate page that you link to. Here is the formal reference of the Silverlight object element and it's properties (in the tree view to the left), and here are the walkthroughs that show how to add Silverlight to an existing page. You can also create a new Silverlight project with a hosting web application in Visual Studio and then look at the source code of the generated HTML and ASP.NET pages to see how it's done.

here is good article : [How To Use Silverlight Controls in ASP.NET Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33193/How-To-Use-Silverlight-Controls-in-ASP-NET-Grid) which give your more idea on this topic